# Синхронизация метода не всегда работает корректно

Tags: java

Выполняю примерный код из учебника Шилдта. Делаю метод синхронизированным, но результат иногда выдается неверный.

```
 public class Caller extends Thread{
    String message;
    CallMe target;

Caller(CallMe targ, String s ){
    target = targ;
    message = s;

    start();
}

public void run() {
    target.call(message);
}
}


public class CallMe {
synchronized public void call(String msg) {
    System.out.print("[" + msg);

    System.out.println("]");
}
}

public class Synch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
CallMe target = new CallMe();
Caller  ob1 = new Caller(target, "Добро пожаловать");
Caller  ob2 = new Caller(target, "в синхронизированный");
Caller ob3 = new Caller(target, "мир!");

try {


    ob1.join();
    ob2.join();
    ob3.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("Прервано");
}
    }

}
```

Иногда результат возвращается верный:

> [Добро пожаловать] [в синхронизированный] [мир!]
>
> А иногда: [Добро пожаловать] [мир!] [в синхронизированный]

Comment: синхронизация != порядок выполнения. Одновременно запущенные треды не обязательно сохраняют порядок выполнения.

Answer (score 1):

Оба результата являются "верными".

Ведь ключевое слово `synchronized` лишь гарантирует что помеченный им блок не будет выполняться одновременно в разных потоках, но никак не гарантирует последовательность запусков таких блоков.

В данном случае если один из запущенных потоков вызвал target.call(message), то все остальные, которые пытаются сделать то же самое, подвисают до тех пор пока первый поток не вернёт управление. Когда первый поток заканчивает вывод первой фразы, то какой именно из оставшихся запущенных потоков захватит управление - зависит от удачи. В одном случае это второй поток, в другом - третий, соответственно оставшийся поток будет также дожидаться его завершения.

Для того, чтобы наглядно продемонстрировать, передайте в метод call две фразы и выведите их через небольшую паузу. Т.е.

```
synchronized public void call(String msg1, String msg2) {
    System.out.print("[" + msg1 + "]");
    try {
       Thread.sleep(1000); // пауза
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    System.out.print("[" + msg2 + "]");
}
```

(доработку остального кода для передачи двух фраз оставлю на ваше усмотрение)

Теперь попробуйте запустить со словом `synchronized` у метода и без него.

Comment: Спасибо большое!